# Image Loading in Thread Makes Navigation Transition Choppy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I have an app where a user clicks a photo thumbnail which triggers the next viewcontroller to be pushed on the navigation stack which is responsible for displaying a larger version of the picture. When the photo thumbnail button is pushed, I send the photos alasset reference to the next viewcontroller which loads it in its viewDidLoad method as follows:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
^{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    UIImageView *tempMyImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[[self myAsset] defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]]];
    [self setMyImageView: tempMyImageView];
    [myViewContainer addSubview: [self myImageView]]; 
    [tempMyImageView release];
    [pool drain];
});
```

Everything seems to work OK, except for when I send a large image (like one I took from my camera), the navigation transition is choppy. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You might try just loading the image after the transition is done.

Also of note is that you're not actually doing that in a new thread, as you specified the main queue. Not that that would be a good idea here, as you don't want to execute UI code on another thread.